# How to change the background color of div based on selected color from ng- repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, background, angularjs-ng-repeat

```js
var addnew = angular.module('tailorapp',[]);


addnew.controller('mainController', function($scope,$rootScope) {
console.log('dd');
$scope.colors = [{
    c: 'green'
  }, {
   c: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    c: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
}];




});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="tailorapp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div style="height:100px;width:300px;border:1px red solid; background:red" ng-style="{'background-color': {{selectedcolor.scr}} }" ng-model="divison">

    </div>


    <div ng-repeat="color in colors" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block"  ng-style="{'background-color': color.c}"  ng-click="selectedcolor.scr=black">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this snippet.What I am trying to get is onclick of any of the color from below 3 colors, background color of above div should get changed accordingly.

Help me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first declare `$scope.selectedcolor = {scr:"red"}` in the controller.

Then change the `ng-click` to this

`ng-click="selectedcolor.scr = color.c"`

Demo

```js
var addnew = angular.module('tailorapp',[]);


addnew.controller('mainController', function($scope,$rootScope) {
console.log('dd');

$scope.selectedcolor = {scr:"red"}
$scope.colors = [{
    c: 'green'
  }, {
   c: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    c: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
}];




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<div ng-app="tailorapp" ng-controller="mainController">
   
    
    <img  style="height:100px;width:300px;border:1px red solid;opacity: 0.5" src="http://singer.developer.12thdoor.com/apis/media/tenant/image/estimate/11721715563956.png" ng-style="{'background-color': selectedcolor.scr }" ng-model="divison">
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="color in colors" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block"  ng-style="{'background-color': color.c}"  ng-click="selectedcolor.scr = color.c">
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What would I will need to do, if I want to replace div with image, means whatever color is changing, it should get show in that transparent image.

Comment: just add `opacity` style along with the background color

Comment: can you give example, if possible

Comment: check the demo again

Comment: Thanks but I want to add color in image rather in background, like in that demo color should be change in circle part.its transparent png image

Comment: if you want to do that create a another div and put that div on top of image. then make that div transparent.

Comment: It wil be great if you could help me with example for this.Thanks for all this solutions.

Comment: first try it on your own. if have any problems during process then ask. :D

Comment: Actually I was trying this since yesterday but due to some errors, I revert back and start it over again and that is why I started from basic from div background color to finally color of image.

Comment: check demo again

Comment: But its changing the background color, I want to change the inner circle color before bag one.As far I know, if image is transparent then its possible to do, that where I m struck.

Comment: you can't do that. since image container is square it will fill the whole container

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `selectedcolor` object

```js
var addnew = angular.module('tailorapp', []);
addnew.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.selectedcolor = {};
  $scope.colors = [{
    c: 'green'
  }, {
    c: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    c: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
  }];
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="tailorapp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div style="height:100px;width:300px;border:1px red solid; background:red" ng-style="{'background-color': selectedcolor.scr }" ng-model="divison">

  </div>


  <div ng-repeat="color in colors" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block" ng-style="{'background-color': color.c}" ng-click="selectedcolor.scr = color.c;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have selectedcolor object to be declared in your scope. Simply add it to your scope object like this -

```
addnew.controller('mainController', function($scope,$rootScope) {
console.log('dd');
$scope.selectedcolor = ""
$scope.colors = [{
    c: 'green'
  }, {
   c: '#F8F8F8'
  }, {
    c: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
}];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of your code.

```
<html ng-app="tailorapp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ng app</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var addnew = angular.module('tailorapp',[]);

    addnew.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.colors = [{
        c: 'green'
     }, {
        c: '#F8F8F8'
     }, {
        c: 'rgb(50, 77, 32)'
    }];



    $scope.setColor = function(value){
          $scope.selectedcolor = value;
    }


  });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="tailorapp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div style="height:100px;width:300px;border:1px red solid; background:red" ng-style="{'background-color': selectedcolor }" ng-model="divison">

</div>


<div ng-repeat="color in colors" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block"  ng-style="{'background-color': color.c}"  ng-click="setColor(color.c)">
    {{color.c}}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```